# Why won't my for/if loop work for renaming sequence names in a fasta file in bash

Tags: bash, loops, command-line, fasta

I am currently working on a bioinformatics project, and have been assigned the role of editing some genetic sequence files (fasta/.fa) to be viable for the next stage of processing. I am doing this on the command line linux with bash.

With how the files have been obtained, each read within the file has been assigned an arbitrary name following this format for 1-1587663 (denoted x) V1_x.

For the next step of my reads, I need to format these names within the file following a specific naming pattern. This is where all empty spaces must contain a 0. For example, V1_1 must be reformatted to V1_0000001, V1_15 must be reformatted to V1_0000015, V1_1050 must be formatted to V1_0001050, eventually ending with V1_1587663.

I will give an example of how one file is laid out:

> V1_1 flag=1 multi=9.0000 len=342\
> AAGGAGTGATGGCATGGCGTGGGACTTCTCCACCGACCCCGAGTTCCAGGAGAAGCTCGACTGGGTCGAGCGGTTCTGCCAGGAAAGGGTCGAGCCGCTCGACTATGTGTTTCCCCACGCGGTGCGCTGGCCAGACCCGGTGGTAAAGGCGTACGTCCGCGAACTCCAGCAGGAGGTCAAGGACCAGGGCCTGTGGGCGATCTTCCTCGACCGGGAACTAGGTGGCCCGGGCTTCGGACAGCTCAGGCTGGCTCTGCTCAACGAGGTGATCGGCCGCTATCCCGGCGCGCCCGCGATGTTCGGTGCCGCGGCGCCCGATACCGGGAA
> V1_2 flag=1 multi=9.0000 len=330
> ATCTTCACCCAGCTCGGCAGCATGTTTCCCGTGGCGATGGAGTGCAGCATCGAGCCCAGGCAGATCACCAGCCCGGCGTCTTTCAACTGCGCGGCGTAGGCGTCCTGCGCCGCGTTCATATCGGTAATCGTATCGGGCAGCGGGCCGTCGTCGCGCAGGCTGCCCGCCAGCACGAACGGAATCCCAGAGCGCACGCATTCGTACAGGATGCCTTCCCGCAGGCATCCGCCCTCCACGGCCTGCCGGACGCTCCCGGCGCGATAGATCGCATTGATGGCGCGCATGTGATTGCGGTGCCCGTGCTCTTCCTGCCTCCCGTCGCTCAGCCGC\

I am currently trying to write a loop which would do this all in one go, as it is a lot of reads and I have multiple of these genetic sequence fasta files.

I don't want to ruin my file so I have created a copy of the file with the first 5000 reads in to test my code.

The code I have been trying to make work is as follows

```
for i in {1..5000}

do 

if [ "$i" -le "9"]; then

sed -i 's/V1_i/V1_000000i/' testfile.fa

elif [["$i" -gt "9"] && ["i" -le "99"]]; then

sed -i s/V1_i/V1_00000i/' testfile.fa

elif [["i" -gt "99"] && ["i" -le "999"]]; then

sed -i s/V1_i/V1_0000i/' testfile.fa

elif [["i" -gt "999"] && ["i" -le "9999"]]; then

sed -i s/V1_i/V1_000i/' testfile.fa

fi

done
```

I will rewrite the code below to explain what I think each line should be doing

```
for i in {1..5000} - **Denoting that it should be ran with i standing as 1-5000**

do 

if [ "$i" -le "9"]; then **If 'i' is less than 9 then do...**

sed -i 's/V1_i/V1_000000i/' testfile.fa **replace V1_i with V1_000000i within testfile.fa**

elif [["$i" -gt "9"] && ["i" -le "99"]]; then **else if 'i' is more than 9 but equal to or less than 99 then do....**

sed -i s/V1_i/V1_00000i/' testfile.fa **replace V1_i with V1_000000i within testfile.fa**

elif [["i" -gt "99"] && ["i" -le "999"]]; then

sed -i s/V1_i/V1_0000i/' testfile.fa

elif [["i" -gt "999"] && ["i" -le "9999"]]; then

sed -i s/V1_i/V1_000i/' testfile.fa

fi

done
```

The result I get evertime is 4 lots of 'command not found' as pasted below, per number in the range.

```
[1: command not found
[[1: command not found
[[1: command not found
[[1: command not found
[2: command not found
[[2: command not found
[[2: command not found
[[2: command not found

etc until 5000
```

I assume I must have something wrong with how I've written the code, but as someone who is new to this, I can't see what is wrong.

Thank you for reading, if you can help that is very much appreciated. If you need anymore details, I will gladly try and help to the best of my ability. Unfortunately, I can't share the exact files I'm working on (I know this isn't helpful sorry) as I do not have permission.

Comment: Please paste your program into https://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix everything it tells you. Without even trying to understand what your code does, I see mismatched quotes, lack of spacing in `[...]` and `[[...]]`, incorrect syntax for multiple conditions...

Comment: Thank you, that shellcheck was super useful and has managed to get me past the error codes I was stuck on! I will be back if I can’t fix the new codes, but it’s progress! 

Comment: Well, shellcheck.net is useful but what you're trying to do is so sub-optimal that you need to rewrite the code from scratch. Start by reading the file line by line in a `while` loop; once you have the current line stored in a variable then you can really start the processing.

Comment: As it is presented in the question, your fasta file is not actually in fasta format.  I suspect that you have been tripped up by at least the significance of the leading `>` character to markdown.  I suggest that you edit the the question to format the file excerpt as code: select it and press the `{}` button, then clean up any artifacts of previous attempts to format it.  I would do it myself, but I'm not 100% sure of my diagnosis.

Answer (score 0):

#### Shell syntax

> The result I get evertime is 4 lots of 'command not found' as pasted
> below, per number in the range.
>
> ```
> [1: command not found
> [[1: command not found
> [[1: command not found
> [[1: command not found
> [2: command not found
> [[2: command not found
> [[2: command not found
> [[2: command not found
>
> etc until 5000
> ```

The `[` character is not special to the shell. `[` and `[[` are not operators, but rather an ordinary command and a reserved word, repsectively.  They have no involvement in splitting command lines into words.  Similar applies to `]` and `]]` -- the shell does not automatically break words on either side them.

The `"` character *is* special to the shell, but it does not create a word boundary.  The shell has quoting, but it does not have not quote-delimited strings as a syntactic unit in the sense that some other languages do.

With that in mind, consider this code fragment:

> ```
> elif [["$i" -gt "9"] && ["i" -le "99"]]; then
> ```

Because neither `[[` nor `"` produce a word break, `[["$i"` expands to a single word, for example `[[1`, which, given its position, is interpreted as the name of a command to execute.  There being no built-in command by that name and no program by that name in the path, executing that command fails with "command not found".

You need to insert whitespace to make separate words separate (but see also below):

```
elif [[ "$i" -gt "9" ] && [ "i" -le "99" ]]; then
```

Moreover, again, `[` is a *command* and `[[` is a reserved word naming a built-in command. `]` is an argument with special meaning to the `[` command, and `]]` is an argument with special significance to the `[[` built-in.  Although they (intentionally) have a similar appearance, **these are not analogous to parentheses**.  You don't need to impose grouping here anyway.  The `&&` operator already separates commands, and the overall pipeline does not need to be explicitly demarcated as a group.  This would be correct and more natural:

```
elif [[ "$i" -gt "9" ]] && [[ "$i" -le "99" ]]; then
```

Furthermore, although it is not wrong, it is unnecessary and a bit weird to quote your numbers.  The case is amore nuanced for the expansions of `$i`, since its values are fully under your control, but "always quote your variable expansions" is a pretty good rule until your shell scripting is strong enough for you to decide for yourself when you can do otherwise.  So, this is where we arrive:

```
elif [[ "$i" -gt 9 ]] && [[ "$i" -le 99 ]]; then
```

You will want to do likewise throughout your script.

---

#### But wait, there's more!

I think the changes described above would make your script work, but it would be extremely slow, because it will make 5000 passes through the whole file.  And on the whole 1.5M entry file, you would need a version that made 1.5M passes through the whole half-gigabyte-ish of data.  It would take years to complete.

That approach is not viable, not really even for the 5000 lines. You need something that will make only a single pass through the file, or at worst a small, fixed number of passes.  I think a one-pass approach would be possible with `sed`, but it would take a complex and very cryptic `sed` expression.  I'm a `sed` fan, but I would recommend `awk` for this, or even shell without any external tool.

A pure-shell version could be built with the `read` and `printf` built-in commands combined with some of the shell's other features.  An `awk` version could be expressed as a not-overly-complex one-liner.  Details of either of these options depends on the file syntax, however, which, as I commented on the question, I think you have misrepresented.